# Уменьшить ширину Line Chart в библиотеке MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android-studio, view, диаграммы

Создаю график с одной точкой 0.

```
tonnageChart= mView.findViewById(R.id.tonnageChart);
    tonnageChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    tonnageChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
  settonaage = new LineDataSet(null, getString(R.string.tonnage_chart));
    settonaage.addEntry(new Entry(1,0));
   dataSetstonnage = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSetstonnage.add(settonaage);
    datatonnage = new LineData(dataSetstonnage);
    tonnageChart.setData(datatonnage);
```

При нажатии на "за все время" я получаю все данные сразу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда я получаю линейный график со всеми данными, я получаю то что мне нужно, отображаются они полностью.

НО. когда после этого я сокращаю данные (перезаписываю).

```
    settonaage.clear(); //почистил предыдущие данные

 myRef.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            temp= (int) dataSnapshot.child("Training").getChildrenCount();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child("Training").getChildren()) {
                if (i > temp-7) {
                    settonaage.addEntry(new Entry(i, Float.parseFloat(postSnapshot.child("Tonnage").getValue().toString())));
                }
                i++;
            }
```

добавил последние значения. НО в итоге я получаю вот такой график.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все позиции Х остаются и не перезаписываются. а мне нужно чтобы новый график растянулся на всю область.

Comment: я видимо не на то кликнул при выборе тега.

Comment: может [обновить надо](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Dynamic-&-Realtime-Data#keep-in-mind)

Comment: при обновлении не помогает. иксы считает с нуля даже если я выбираю первое отображение  не все тренировки а последние.